# How do I get a text from div using requests module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, request

The problem is that I can't understand how to get a text from div (like div's text).
So here is my code:

```
 soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text,features="html.parser")
 for link in soup.findAll('div',{'class':'item-sub-info'}):
        value = link.get('dont_know_what_to_write')
        print(value)
```

That is the information:

```
<div class="item-sub-info" style="border-right: 5px solid crimson
!important;">              
  **Factory New /
  Covert Knife**
  / <span class="poptip" data-toggle="tooltip" title=""...></div>
```

And I need to get *Factory New / Covert* Knife from it, by using an unknown parameter in link.get(???). What should it be ???

Comment: did you try .text?

Comment: @Chris If I write this:
value = link.get('.text') or value = link.get('text')
I just get lines were is written 'None'

Comment: maybe try print(link.text)

Comment: @Chris yep know it works. No the way I wanted by using get, but still...

Comment: You should be looking at BeautifulSoup documentation. I don't think your question has anything to do with requests module. I think @Lolkek2281337 solution should work. You can also look at [get-text()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text)